# How to properly link dynamic libraries on Linux platforms

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, shared-libraries

Suppose my project uses the `C++` language and the library to be linked uses the `C` language.

```
project(test)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
```

For the `Windows` platform (use `MSVC`), we can use `add_library+target_link_libraries` to link dynamic libraries.

```
set(this_library_name this_library)
set(dll_path ${parent_path}/this_library.dll)
set(lib_path ${parent_path}/this_library.lib)

add_library(
        ${this_library_name}
        SHARED
        IMPORTED
)

set_target_properties(
        ${this_library_name}
        PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${dll_path}
        IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${lib_path}
        LINKER_LANGUAGE C
)

get_target_property(
        target_binary_directory
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
)

add_custom_command(
        TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${target_binary_directory}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Copying dll from '${dll_path}' to '${target_binary_directory}'."
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${dll_path} ${target_binary_directory}/
)

target_link_libraries(
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE
        ${this_library_name}
)
```

But this does not seem to work on the `Linux` platform (use `GCC`).

Create exported libraries as on the `Windows` platform.

```
set(lib1_name lib1)
set(lib1_path ${parent_path}/liblib1.so)

add_library(
        ${lib1_name}
        SHARED
        IMPORTED
)

set_target_properties(
        ${lib1_name}
        PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${lib1_path}
        LINKER_LANGUAGE C
        IMPORTED_NO_SONAME ON
)

set(lib2_name lib2)
set(lib2_path ${parent_path}/liblib2.so)

add_library(
        ${lib2_name}
        SHARED
        IMPORTED
)

set_target_properties(
        ${lib2_name}
        PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${lib2_path}
        LINKER_LANGUAGE C
        IMPORTED_NO_SONAME ON
)

get_target_property(
        target_binary_directory
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY
)

add_custom_command(
        TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRE_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${target_binary_directory}

        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Copying so from '${lib1_path}' to '${target_binary_directory}'."
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${lib1_path} ${target_binary_directory}/

        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "Copying so from '${lib2_path}' to '${target_binary_directory}'."
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${lib2_path} ${target_binary_directory}/
)
```

Use them

```
# not work
target_link_libraries(
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE
        ${lib1_name}
        ${lib2_name}
)

# empty
get_target_property(
        my_project_linked_libraries
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        LINK_LIBRARIES
)

# ---------------------------------------------------------

# work well
target_link_libraries(
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE
        ${lib1_path}
        ${lib2_path}
)

# ${parent_path}/liblib1.so;${parent_path}/liblib2.so
get_target_property(
        my_project_linked_libraries
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        LINK_LIBRARIES
)
```

Although linking these so files directly seems to work, it is obviously not a decent way to do it.

Comment: add_library+target_link_libraries should work on any platform. Please, **elaborate** what "not work" part means on Linux. Assuming strings `${lib1_name}` and `${lib2_name}` are not empty when you call `target_link_libraries`, the property `LINK_LIBRARIES` should contain those strings (or some other ones, see "Note" in https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LINK_LIBRARIES.html)

Comment: TLDR, please provide [mcve] . Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake of using `${}` :(

```
set(this_library_path ${parent_path}/libthis_library.so)

add_library(
        this_library
        SHARED
        IMPORTED
)

set_target_properties(
        this_library
        PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${this_library_path}
        LINKER_LANGUAGE C
        IMPORTED_NO_SONAME ON
)

# ---------------------------------
target_link_libraries(
        ${PROJECT_NAME}
        PRIVATE
        this_library # <----- DO NOT USE ${this_library}!!!
)
```